# Trying to delete extra records created by web app development platform using SQL object

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I've tried many SQL statements and failed every time. I want to have an SQL object kick off after the records are written to the file and get rid of the records where the concatenation of JOBNO || BATCHNO is not equal to the JOBNOFULL

```
JOBNOFULL          JOBNO              BATCHNO
LF00698 14295001   LF00698            14295001 (Keep these records)
LF00698 14295001   LF00698 PKG1       14295001 (delete these records)
LF00698 14295001   LF00698 PKG2       14295001 (delete these records)
```

any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by *an SQL object kick off after the records are written to the file*?

Comment: `I've tried many SQL statements...` But what statements were those? We don't want to spend time suggesting things you've already found won't work. Also `I want to have an SQL object kick off after the records are written to the file...` What are you expecting to execute the `kick off`? What process are you running now?

Answer (score 1):

See the SQL statement [CREATE TRIGGER](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhctrigger.htm) This will create a trigger that executes your code when a row is added to the table.